# Run 2 select statement in DB2 depending of the result of one of them

Tags: stored-procedures, db2

I'm trying to do an SP in DB2 with 2 select statements. If the first select returns null, perform the second one.

For example

```
Select a, b, c from table A where...
```

--If first select returns null

```
Select a, from table B where...
```

I tried a lot of ideas but none of them worked.

Thanks

Comment: What did you try, and what was wrong with the result?

Comment: I tried doing IF EXIST operation but didnt worked. Maybe i did it just wrong. Tried to set a variable to the result of the first select but didnt work either

Comment: Please show code that you tried. And "didn't work" isn't a problem statement. What is wrong with the results? What did you expect, and what did you get instead? Please edit the question with this information.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this general pattern, of course you will have to adapt your two result sets to match

```
WITH first AS 
(
SELECT ..result1.. FROM table1
WHERE ..clause1.. 
)
SELECT ..result1.. FROM first
UNION
SELECT ..result2.. FROM table2
WHERE 0=(SELECT COUNT(1) FROM first)
AND
..clause2..
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple way to write that

```
Select a, from table B where...
and not exists (select * from table a where...)
union 
select a,.. from table A)
```